# How to access to an element created on the fly in angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, angular12

I am using a table similar to datatables.net (it is not the same, but very similar) in an angular 12 project.

I need to populate the table with data like:

| Id | Name | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | Delete |
| 1 | Conn | Delete |

The "Delete" action is a button that looks like a link and it would delete the current row.

When the user comes to the table for first time it needs to be empty. With a button the user imports data from a csv file.

| Id | Name | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |

In the html component the table looks like this:

```
<table data-table="tt__table">
</table>
<input type="button" value="Import" (click)="importData()" />
```

When I import the data from csv in typescript I have something like:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {       
  let options = {
    data: {
      headings: ["Id", "Name", "Actions"],
      rows: [
        {
          data: ["", "", ""]
        }
       ]
     }
   };
        
   this.tableElement = document.querySelector('[data-table=\"tt__table\"]') as Element;
   this.table = new Table(this.tableElement, options);            
}
...
importData(): void{
  let importedData = {
          "type": 'csv',
          "data": '0,John,<button data-toggle="tt__btn" class="tt__btn-link (click)="deleteRow($event)">Delete</button>'
       };
        
  this.table.deleteAll();
  this.table.import(importedData); // rows are created on the fly using vanilla js.
        
  const tableButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle=\"tt__btn\"]');
  tableButtons.forEach(button => {
    new Button(button, {})
  });
}
        
deleteRow(event): void{
             // Delete row.
          }
```

The imported data looks fine after click on "Add" button:

| Id | Name | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | Delete |

But when I click in "Delete" button it does not do anything.

I suspect the reason is that Angular cannot see the new DOM elements created because the HTML after clicking on "Add" button looks like this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td data-content="0">0</td>
     <td data-content="John">John</td>
     <td data-content="Delete">
        <button data-toggle="tt__btn" class="tt__btn-link" (click)="deleteRow($event)">Delete</button>
     </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

But in other components where I use "(click)" angular directive, the final HTML does not show the "(click)" directive.

I am very new to angular, could you please help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: would you mind showing the code inside the function DeleteRow(event)?

Comment: In fact I have only this:

```
    deleteRow(event): void{
      console.log(event);
    }
```
Because first I need to see that "deleteRows" is being called, but that is not happening

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using Renderer2 to listen DOM events.

1. First I injected the renderer2 in constructor:

   ```
   import { AfterViewInit, Renderer2, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
   unlistener: () => void;
   ...
   constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
   ...
   }
   ```
2. Then I added a listener to renderer instance, which listen to DOM table "click" events and call to "deleteRow" function:

   ```
   ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     ...
     this.tableElement = document.querySelector('[data-table=\"tt__table\"]') as Element;

     unlistener = this.renderer.listen(this.tableElement, "click", event => 
     this.deleteRow(event));

     this.table = new Table(this.tableElement, options);
     ...
   }
   ```
3. "deleteRow" function catch the click events in the table and delete rows according to the button id (which has the user id):

   ```
   deleteRow(event: any): void {
     let userId: string = '';
     let userToDelete: User;
     let userIndex: number = -1;

     if (event !== null && event !== undefined) {
       if (event.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement) {
         userId = event.target.id;
           if (userId !== '') {
              userToDelete = this.selectedUsers.find(u => u.userId === userId) as User;
             if (userToDelete !== null && userToDelete !== undefined) {
               userIndex = this.selectedUsers.indexOf(userToDelete);
               this.selectedUsers.splice(userIndex, 1);
               this.updateTable();
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   ```
4. In ngOnDestroy() hook add unlistener to stop listening DOM events:

   ```
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.unlistener();
    }
   ```

Thanks for your replies, specially to @Mohamed Babei, his answer shed the light to my research.

This solution is based on [Four ways of listening to DOM events in Angular (Part 3: Renderer2.listen)](https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/four-ways-of-listening-to-dom-events-in-angular-part-3-renderer2-listen-14c6fe052b59) article.

Answer (score 0):

You can not bind angular events this way so you need to render your data in table angular way for example useing '''*ngFor''' or if you want go your way use addEventListener( click ) after rendering content

Comment: I have tried using "onclick=deleteRow", but I have the following error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteRow is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (users:1)"

Even if I put the "deleteRow" function in the component Html template inside <script></script> tags. What am I doing wrong in this last approach?